# How can I add text to the end of user input?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, authentication

I have been given some spaghetti code for a login page to fix.

We've got two input fields ID and Password.

Here's what I've been asked.
So in terms of a user inputting their ID, I want to add '@email.com' onto the end.

Im assume placeholder="@email.com" would work if i could align it to the right, but I also need to it to be added into the POST method. So if the user entered 'ID123' it would post 'ID123@email.com'

Here is the form:

```html
<form action="command.php" formmethod="post">
       <div class="ID">User ID:<br><input name="ID" type="text"><br></div>
        <div class="Pass"> Password:<br><input name="pwd" type="password"></div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">
```

Can anyone help? Is it even possible?

Comment: why not just: `$user_id=$_POST['ID'].'@email.com';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder in the input type in HTML will just give a hint in a textbox and it will not be added into the input of the user. What you need to do is catch the input type in the `command.php` you created and add it.

for example, in the `command.php`

`$ID = $_POST['ID'].'@gmail.com'`

Comment: concatenation always catch me when switching from java to php always. lol

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, your POST data will contain:

```
$_POST['ID'] = 'test_id';   // Sample Data
$_POST['pwd'] = 'test_pwd'; // Sample Data
```

So, if you want to add @email.com at the end of the ID, you could simply concatenate the field:

```
$_POST['ID'] .= '@email.com';
```

Note: This is a simple solution and doesn't specify SQL injection/vulnerability prevention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like if anyone give `ID123@email.com` as input it will not change but if only give `ID123` then it will be `ID123@email.com`,then :-

```
$userId=$_POST['ID'];
if(!filter_var($userId, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$userId=$userId.'@email.com';     
}
echo $userId;
```